# Rigid frame deflection and material selection

Tags: structural-engineering, beam, deflection

I'm building a frame that will receive a point load mid span (likely it won't be but want to design for worse case).

The frame is 1.5 x 0.095 square tubing, and it will be skinned with 14ga on one side.  Span is 21" and frame is welded.

My question is how do you determine deflection when a beam is skinned with metal?   Shouldn't this increase its strength?

I want to make it stronger than needed, but not unnecessarily heavy.   I was originally debating between 0.095 and 0.065 wall tubing and 12 vs 14 GA sheeting.

I'm using 2250# for my point loading figure at center of 21" span.

[image]

Comment: Clarify your dimensions, as numbers only are not clear.

Comment: You can estimate a new moment of inertia for the skinned beam using the parallel axis theorem which is in any structures textbook, or wiki, no doubt.

Comment: The sheet metal buckles easily, and given the way it is attached, it usually does not contribute much in stiffness. You won't regret by ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

This a very rough calculation not considering the dynamic load factor of the application of the random load which could be up to three,

$$\sigma = \frac{M}{s}= \frac{2250*21}{4 *0.12953}=91,569lbs >>36000lbs$$

- $\sigma = stress<3600 \text{  A35 steel yield}$
- M = moment inch.lbs
- S = 1.5x1.5 square tube section modulus
  Because the member is significantly under-designed we do not need to investigate the effect of galvanization. It is not going to be adding enogh strength to make the member 2.8 times mor strong.